# get all form details in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

i want list all forms in current project. example
listbox1.items.add(form1.name & form1.text)

i want  load all form details in current project.

the following code give for only open forms.

```
  For linti As Integer = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
      Application.OpenForms.Item(linti).Text
      Application.OpenForms.Item(linti).name
  Next
```

i want all form and its text. what i do sir please help me

Comment: Well, if the OP commonly asks silly questions like this, he probably never got an acceptable answer yet.

Comment: I'll have to take that back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692514/how-can-i-change-form-shape-in-vb-net/692982#692982

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of Linq you could try

```
Dim list = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList(). _
                    SelectMany(Function(s) s.GetTypes()). _
                    Where(Function(p) (p.BaseType Is [GetType]().BaseType AndAlso _
                                       p.Assembly Is [GetType]().Assembly))
For Each type As Type In list
    Dim typeName As String = type.Name
Next
```