# Get All Forms names to list

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I need to collect all the form names to a list. I tried this code, but this code only find forms that are in Master Folder. here is my folder stricture.

[image]

Here is the code that i am using

```
Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim types As Type() = myAssembly.GetTypes()

        For Each myType As Type In types
            MsgBox(myType.BaseType.FullName)
            If myType.BaseType.FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Form" Then

                Dim ProjAndForm = "Mini_Stock_Control." & myType.Name
                Dim objType As Type = Type.[GetType](ProjAndForm) '' Get Type Of your string
                Dim objForm As Control = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(objType), Control)

                    MsgBox(objForm.Text)

            End If
        Next
```

Reference from [http://www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/485398/Call-Form-with-string-name-convert-String-to-Contr)
Any one has a solution? Please help (Please ignore my bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad to all who answers my question. But I solved this problem myself.
The problem that I found is there is an error occurred in the line and program skip loop without giving an error.

```
 Dim objForm As Control = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(objType), Control)
```

So  what I did is put a try catch. It works Now it is ok. works fine.

```
Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim types As Type() = myAssembly.GetTypes()

        For Each myType As Type In types

            If myType.BaseType.FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Form" Then

                Dim ProjAndForm = "Mini_Stock_Control." & myType.Name
                Dim objType As Type = Type.[GetType](ProjAndForm) '' Get Type Of your string

                Try
                    Dim objForm As Control = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(objType), Control)

                        dg.Rows.Add(objForm.Text)

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try



            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
        Dim col As New Generic.List(Of Type)
        Dim list() As System.Reflection.Assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

        For Each asm As Reflection.Assembly In list
            Dim types() As Type = asm.GetTypes()
            For Each t As Type In types
                If t.BaseType Is GetType(Windows.Forms.Form) Then
                    col.Add(t)
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

modified code from: [get all form details in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152739/get-all-form-details-in-vb-net)

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. I solved problem myself. Please read my answer. This answer also suit for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . You will get each report name

```
    Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim types As Type() = myAssembly.GetTypes()

    For Each myType As Type In types

        ' If myType.BaseType.FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Form" Then
        If myType.BaseType.FullName = "System.ComponentModel.Component" Then
            Dim ProjAndForm = "Mini_Stock_Control." & myType.Name
            Dim objType As Type = Type.[GetType](ProjAndForm) '' Get Type Of your string


            If InStr(myType.Name, "Cache") > 0 Then
                Debug.Print(Replace((myType.Name), "Cached", ""))
            End If
          
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: This is very old question. This was already solved. Thank you